# MongDb How To find Element with invalid data

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a very big mongo database collection.

now a nightly job with a lot of task has one task to run over it.

The code runs with a foreach over it like this:

```
var sets = Collection.FindAll();
await sets.ForEachAsync(handler)
```

Now this morning i got:

> System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the
>   Connections property of class
>   SR.BusPortal.DomainModel.Search.StoredConnectionSet: An error occurred
>   while deserializing the DeepLinkToken property of class
>   SR.BusPortal.DomainModel.Search.StoredConnectionStep: Invalid
>   BsonType: 34.

The property on which the error is related to is defined like this:

```
 [IgnoreNull]
 [DataMember(Order = 1390, Name = "lt")]
 public string[] DeepLinkToken { get; set; }
```

Are there any special strings which may be problematic in this array?

Now How can I find out which document has the invalid property ? and what its value was? Is there  a way to select it ? e.g. with mongo chef or the c# api ?

One idea is to read all as BsonDocuments and then manually deserializing them manually `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(doc);`. But is there a better way?

**Update**
I created a small test tool but i didn't get any exception. Do I make an mistake when thinking hat the following code should break / throw  on the specific domunent? Or is it more likely that it was only a temporary bug ?

```
source.FindAll(options).ForEachAsync((doc, pos) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var element = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<StoredConnectionSet>(doc);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                if(Debugger.IsAttached) // I run in debug with an attached VS debugger
                {
                    Debugger.Break();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(err);
                throw;
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was not related to the data. It was related to some connectivity issues that sometimes occured.

Not sure why it ends up with this exception but solving the connectivity issue solved this error.